Harmonic drive motor output bearing specifications and bearing arrangements
I'm not a mechanical engineer, but I've been tasked with designing a system that uses a harmonic drive motor (specifically, a LynxDrive). It must rotate a 200kg mass, which is heavily off-center. It only needs to move a few degrees clockwise and counter-clockwise. Here's a simplified diagram:

$F_g$ is caused by the mass, and exerts a moment on the motor+bearing assembly. I've selected a spherical roller bearing to avoid misalignment issues, while the motor has a cross roller output bearing. If the moment is split equally between the two bearings, and my math is correct, each bearing is subject to a radial load of ~$14kN$. I'm not sure about the 50/50 force split, because -I suppose- the most rigid bearing of the two will take more load that the other. Feel free to correct me on that.
My doubt is on the specifications of the motor bearing. I undertand that the dynamic load is only useful for estimating the L10 life, while the static load rating is the load that causes a 0.01% deformation of the rollers and raceways in the motor's bearing. Simple bearings only provide those two specifications, while this motor also has a "permissible radial load". Why is it so much lower than the $C_0$ rating?
As for the what this permissible load is, I've read that it's $C_0$ divided by a safety factor, but then it isn't clear to me why the manufacturer assumed such a big safety factor. Perhaps because this motor is used for robotics? Should I not care about the permissible load then?

If, instead, I must stay below the permissible radial load, what do you recommend to do? I haven't found in literature a bearing arrangment that could work (there would be 3 distinct bearings, over-constraining the shaft, right?). There is a high risk of mis-alignment between the 3 bearings.

You show an "overhung" load. Is that what you mean by off center? How much holding torque is required? Does the rotated load have an off-center CG, like a robot arm, requiring a holding torque from the drive? Are you including a shaft brake?

By the way, note three on the chart answers and explains the reasons to one of your questions.

@PhilSweet you're right, it's a overhung load. I've updated the picture because a friend told me I didn't draw a fully equivalent diagram of the system. The required torque for rotation is 600Nm. The motor has a holding brake.

Short answer is you actually need an ME for this. The harmonic drives do have some unusual restrictions compared to other drives. You probably want a motor shaft connection free of side loads and moments on the harmonic drive shaft. Use a jackshaft supported by two bearings, and hang the harmonic drive on a torque arm. Bearing quality needs to be very good because harmonic drives have flexible internal gear parts that need very accurate and consistent alignment. Most harmonic drives have a through-shaft design at least as an option. If Linksys has that, you can mount the torque arm between the bearings on the shaft.

Thanks for the suggestions! I will put the motor on a torque arm and use two bearings, or perhaps the motor on a rigid mount and a flexible coupling to the shaft (again supported by two bearings). Unfortunately I'm the new hire in a large company, and I've been left alone on a big project since day one. I'm an electronics engineer but management thinks every engineer can make anything.
